# How to detect attached usb devices from java code

Tags: java, usb

I am creating an java application that is to detect the list of attached devices  to the system.When i run the application it was not showing any of the attached devices...this is my java code please help me to work this

```
package com.mqs.lakshman;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class Usbactivity 
{

    static String driveLetter="";
    static FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        File[] f = File.listRoots();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
              String drive = f[i].getPath();
              String displayName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]);
              String type = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(f[i]);
              boolean isDrive = fsv.isDrive(f[i]);
              boolean isFloppy = fsv.isFloppyDrive(f[i]);
              boolean canRead = f[i].canRead();
              boolean canWrite = f[i].canWrite();

              if (canRead && canWrite && !isFloppy && isDrive && (type.toLowerCase().contains("removable") || type.toLowerCase().contains("rimovibile"))) 
              {
                System.out.println("Detected PEN Drive: " + drive + " - "+ displayName);
                driveLetter = drive;
                break;
              }                     
            }

            if (driveLetter.equals("")) 
            {

            } 
            else
            {


            }


    }

}
```